# Is it possible to get the text channel that a user is in through discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a logging bot for storing messages in a text file. But I want it to focus on one specific text channel to monitor. Is there any way I could do this?

Code:

```
import discord
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)
    async def on_message(self, message):
        file = open("logs.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
        if message.author != self.user:
            file.write(str(message.author) + ": " + message.content + "\n\n")
        else:
            return
        file.close()
        if message.content == "!logs":
            file = open("logs.txt", encoding="utf-8")
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Logs in this channel", description="All Messages In This Channel")
            embed.add_field(name='logs', value=file.read())
            await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
            file.close()
        if message.content == "!deletelogs":
            with open("logs.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8"):
                pass
        if message.content == "!lockbothere":
            # Lock Bot To TextChannel
bot = MyClient()
bot.run("lolno")
```

Comment: you could use `print(message)` or `print( dir(message) )` to see what you get when function is executed. Or `print( type(message) )` to see what object/class you get and search this class in `discord.py` documentation to check what information you can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just the check message channel and work with the id or the name.

If you put in the following print statement you'll see the values and then can add your conditional statements as desired.

```py
print(f'message channel is {message.channel} id {message.channel.id} name {message.channel.name}')
```

`message.channel` will return the discord.channel.TextChannel object (for text channels)

`message.channel.id` will return the integer value of the channel id

`message.channel.name` will return the string value of the channel name (like "general")